# Is this a category?

Tags: category-theory

In Awodey's book Category Theory (second edition), on page 5 he asks if we have a category by taking "sets as objects and as arrows, those $f\, :\, A \rightarrow B$ such that for all $b \in B$, the subset $f^{-1}(b)\subseteq A$ has at most two elements (rather than one)". (The question follows a paragraph explaining why if we take sets to be objects and injective functions to be arrows, we have a category. I understand his explanation.) He seems to suggest the answer is "yes", but if you take $f$ to be a function from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{1,2\}$ and $g$ to be a function from $\{1,2\}$ to $\{1\}$, doesn't $g \circ f$ necessarily fail to be an arrow?

Comment: why the downvote. I think this is a very well posed question.

Comment: Why would it necessarily fail to be an arrow in your opinion ?

Comment: For any function $f$ from $A=\{1,2,3\}$ to $B=\{1,2\}$ we must have an element of $B$ which is paired with at least two elements of $A$. Since every element of $B$ gets paired with the only element of $\{1\}$, we have $g \circ f$ pairing all three elements of $A$ with the only element of $\{1\}$. But then $(g \circ f)^{-1}$ would be a subset of $A$ with three elements, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree . Take:

$f:\{1,2,3,4\} \rightarrow \{1,2\}$ where $f(2)=f(4)=0$ and $f(1)=f(3)=1$

$g:\{1,2\}\rightarrow \{1\}$.

Then $g\circ f$ is not a morphism while $f$ and $g$ are.

---

Here is the actual text:

What if we take sets as objects and as arrows, those $f : A \rightarrow B$ such
that for all $b ∈ B$, the subset
$f ^{-1} (b) ⊆ A$
has at most two elements (rather than one)? Is this still a category? What
if we take the functions such that $f^{−1} (b)$ is finite? infinite? There are lots of such restricted categories of sets and functions.

---

Notice that the example where $f^{-1}(b)$ is asked to be finite is in fact a category. Perhaps that is what he means.

Comment: Nonstandard composition wouldn't help, because as flakmonkey argues, there _does_ exist an arrow $f:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2\}$ as well as a $g:\{1,2\}\to\{1\}$. No matter whether composition is not standard function composition, that won't fix the fact that $\operatorname{Hom}(\{1,2,3\},\{1\})$ as defined is _empty_, so there is nothing $gf$ _can_ be.

Comment: yeah, I copied the part of the book he is talking about, do you agree with my opinion?

Comment: Although the one where he asks $f^{-1}$ to be infinite has no identity.

Comment: x @The: Yes, that sounds like a reasonable interpretation, although one can question the pedagogy of promising "lots of such examples" when only 1 of the 3 examples just given hold water.